# Route an email to specific email address depending on dropdown selection in Web Form for Marketers

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

What would be the best way in Web Forms for Marketers to look at a dropdown selection and determine where to route an email depending on what the selection is.  Having multiple selections and either sending the email to sales or support depending on the selection

Answer (score 1):

What you'd want to do is

1. Use the *Send Email Message* save action
2. Invoke the *processMessage* pipeline in *Sitecore.Forms.config* and add a custom processor something like this:

   ```
   public void Process(ProcessMessageArgs args)
   {
       var field = args.Fields.GetEntryByName("myFieldName");
       if (field == null)
       {
           return;
       }

       var selection = field.Value;

       // TODO: select the right e-mail according to selection's value
       var email = "the@mail.com";

       // Append the email
       if (args.To.Length != 0)
       {
           args.To.Append(",");
       }

       args.To.Append(email);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could tag the drop down value selected to the Analytics database (feature available in WFFM) then add all applicants to an engagement plan through a save action and, by using rules looking at the tagged value, route them through different actions sending separate emails. That is, if you want to avoid coding ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web%20forms%20for%20marketers%20v2_3%20reference-usletter.pdf?
In section 2.6 it talks of the submit actions which includes sending emails, and you will have access to the submitted info in the action as well.

You can always write a custom action else.